# Display a list or library from top level site to subsites in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sub-site

I have a SharePoint 2013 web application with a top level site and some subsites, how can I Display a list or library from top level site to subsites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same 2010 method still works in the SharePoint 2013.

- open the site in designer
- select all document views of the list /library
- then save XsLtListViewWebpart
- Now edit the page where you want to display it.
- upload and add the webpart.

Please check this for compete steps.[SharePoint 2010 display list or library on another site](http://www.microsofttechnology.net/2013/04/sharepoint-2010-display-list-or-library.html)

Comment: Thank you you are right, but How can I make a data view from top level library?

Comment: did you check the blog and follow the instructions?

Comment: yes,It works great in sharepoint 2013

Comment: then what is the question, i am confused?

Comment: In sharepoint designer 2013 top level site I created a data view from one library, then I saved that in "to site gallery", and I used it in subsites, Thank you.

Comment: link given in answer is not working

Comment: the broken link can be accessed through web archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20131114212951/http://www.microsofttechnology.net/2013/04/sharepoint-2010-display-list-or-library.html

Answer (score 0):

When you say « top level site » I assume you mean a site collection.

You can try to use a **Content Query Web Part (CQWP)**.

Using this webpart you can configure it to show content from anywhere in your site collection (list or document library).

Note that if your site is a team site, be sure to active publishing features or you wont see the Content Query Web Part in the list of available webparts.

Comment: How can I make a data view from top level library?