# Same list for multiple site collection/sites

Tags: list, site, share

I'm searching for a solution to get my list viewable on different sites (or site collections if possible). But i would like to do it with oob. So my purpose is to have a single list that multiple sites would share and use values from it as look ups but i'm not aware if we can do this with sharepoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You've found the headache that a lot of administrators deal with when
>   trying to share data between site collections. The short answer is you
>   can not do this out of the box.  You are able to do it in sub sites
>   because all the data in theory lives under that one site collection.
>   If you want to pull data from a list on another site collection you
>   will need to consider a custom solution.
>
> You could consider some sort of roll up or exporting feature from one
>   list in site collection A to the list in site collection B, or a
>   workflow to push that data across, but performance will be an issue
>   and something to consider.

Kindly [check here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e46d1bdb-bdf3-4355-a7ad-c0c0df56970e/display-a-list-from-another-site-collection?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy)

Comment: Yeah but i don't need to only see it. I need to use it too. And can we at least do that for sites of the same site collection?

Comment: We  can use it to same sites of the same site collection by using list view webpart / Content Query Web Part. See tutorial here...http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144319/display-a-list-or-library-from-top-level-site-to-subsites-in-sharepoint-2013

Comment: As you asked for site collection as well that's why i gave my answer with having both in mind.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for taking the time to answer me.

Comment: Thanks. Kindly mark the answer as correct so others can get benefit from it.